# How to only sync the new records from table A to table B in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Does any one how can I only sync the new records from table A to table B in SSIS?

I have 2 tables which table A and table B. Table A will be update time to time from user. However, records from table B is sync from table A every 30 mins. I have created a SSIS job to do the sync, see below for more details:

[image]

I have an issue here, every times when I'm ruining the job, it will copy all data from table A and insert into table B (this causing duplicate records had been insert). Any way that I can set the job so that it will only sync the new records into table B?

Comment: The only way to do it is to know beforehand _what_ the new records are. There are many ways to do this but in general it is called CDC. You need to build some CDC infrastructure that SSIS can use. SSIS will not do this natively. Tell us some mor about your source - how many records? Are there any 'datetime modified' fields in the source?

Comment: Maybe use a Execute SQL task with script: insert into B where not exists (then check that on you keys)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a MERGE statement into an execute SQL Task.

Please review some examples about how to use the merge command:

- [Using MERGE in SQL Server to insert, update and delete at the same time](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/)
- [The MERGE Statement in SQL Server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

Kind Regards,

Paul